# Are mudras limited to hands?

Tags: spiritual-level, mudra

What are ***Mudras*** ? How they help human maintain physical, mental and spiritual equilibrium and what are their type ?

I know this might be huge, but I will only like to have a small brief about ***Mudras***, mostly their types if any, with usage.

My main context is, I have seen suggestion related to *Mudras* which are due to modifiable position of palm and figures. Are *Mudras* related to hands only, or they are also verified through different parts of body.

[image]

Comment: What I think is Mudras are not limited to hands.. shape of body also shows mudras. like Nataraja Mudra of Lord Shiva.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi, for that you require multiple hands, secondly, wherever I searched, I got mudras of hands only.

Comment: Mudras used in worship are all hand gestures only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is first to know the significance of the Mudaras.

Gheranda Samhita is a manual of yoga taught by Gheranda to Chanda Kapali. Unlike other hatha yoga texts, the Gheranda Samhita speaks of a sevenfold yoga:

Shatkarma for purification
 Asana for strengthening
**Mudra for steadying**
 Pratyahara for calming
 Pranayama for lightness
 Dhyana for perception
 Samādhi for isolation

more over [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mudras_(yoga)) in which there are number of mudras are said. which are given as under.

**Main Mudras**

1. Hasta (hand mudras)
2. Mana (head mudras)
3. Kaya (postural mudras)
4. Bandha (lock mudras)
5. Adhara (perineal mudras)

**Hasta (hand mudras)**

Hasta mudras are conducive for meditation, and help in internalisation.

**Name in Sanskrit** -- **Translation(s) in English**
Anjali Mudra  - Gesture of reverence
Dhyana Mudra  - Psychic gesture of meditation
Vāyu Mudra    - Psychic gesture of air
Shunya Mudra  - Psychic gesture of void or empty
Prithvi Mudra - Psychic gesture of earth
Varuna Mudra  - Psychic gesture of Rain
Shakti Mudra  - Psychic gesture of Power
Apāna Mudra   - Psychic gesture of life force
Gyana Mudra   - Psychic gesture of knowledge
Chin Mudra    - Psychic gesture of consciousness
Chinmya Mudra -
Dhyana Mudra  -
Yoni Mudra    - Attitude of the womb or source
Bhairav Mudra - Fierce or terrifying attitude
Hridaya Mudra - Heart gesture

**Mana (head mudras)**

Mana mudras are an important part of Kundalini yoga, and many are important meditation techniques in their own right.

**Name in Sanskrit** -- **Translation(s) in English**

Shambhavi Mudra   - Eyebrow centre gazing
Nasikagra Drishti - Nosetip gazing
Khecarī mudrā     - Tongue lock
Kaki mudra        - The crow's beak
Bhuangini Mudra   - Cobra respiration
Bhoochari Mudra   - Gazing into nothingness
Akashi mudra      - Awareness of inner space
Shanmukhi mudra   - Closing the seven gates
Unmani Mudra      - The attitude of mindlessness

**Kaya (postural mudras)**

Kaya mudras combine physical postures with breathing and concentration.

**Name in Sanskrit** -- **Translation(s) in English**

Prana Mudra             - Invocation of energy
Vipareeta Karani Mudra  - Inverted psychic attitude
Yoga Mudra              - Attitude of psychic union
Pashinee Mudra          - Folded psychic attitude
Manduki Mudra           - Gesture of the frog
Tadagi Mudra            - Barrelled abdomen technique

**Bandha (lock mudras)**

Bandha mudras combine mudra and bandha.

**Name in Sanskrit** -- **Translation(s) in English** 
Maha Mudra         - Great psychic attitude
Maha Bheda Mudra   - The great separating attitude
Maha Vedha Mudra   - The great piercing attitude

**Adhara (perineal mudras)**

Adhara mudras redirect prana from the lower centres to the brain.

**Name in Sanskrit** -- **Translation(s) in English** 
Ashwini Mudra          - Horse gesture
Vajroli/Sahajoli Mudra - Thunderbolt/Spontaneous psychic attitude

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question

> What are Mudras ?

*Mudras* act as switches to send Prana to different part of the body just like switches can be used to activate different parts of a circuit:

> Life energy can be intelligently directed through the circuitry of the
>   nervous system to heal mind and body.
>
> *Prana* is the subtle life energy of body and mind. Long ago the ancient
>   Masters discovered how prana moves through the complex circuitry of
>   the human nervous system. They found that specific hand positions, or
>   mudras, can act as extremely subtle switches to channel prana to
>   particular parts of the body. Prana directed with a correct mudra
>   dramatically enhances the natural healing processes in that part of
>   the body.
>
> These mudras were observed by ancient Masters as the natural hand
>   positions displayed by all infants and children at progressive stages
>   of development.

http://www.srisri.com/44-45-text.htm

To answer

> How they help and what are their type ?

[This](http://www.artofliving.org/in-en/yoga/health-and-wellness/mudras-yoga-at-fingertips) page talks about some of the Mudras with their images and
multiple benefits:

**Chin Mudra**

> Hold the thumb and index finger together lightly while extending the
>   remaining three fingers. The thumb and index finger need only touch
>   together, without exerting any pressure. Keep the three extended
>   fingers as straight as possible. The hands can then be placed on the
>   thighs, facing upwards. Now, observe the flow of breath and its
>   effect.

Benefits of Chin Mudra

> Better retention and concentration power
>
> Improves sleep pattern
>
> Increases energy in the body
>
> Alleviates lower backache

**Chinmaya Mudra**

> In this mudra, the thumb and forefinger form a ring and the three
>   remaining fingers are curled into the palms of the hands. Again, the
>   hands are placed on the thighs with palms facing upwards and deep
>   comfortable ujjai breaths are taken. Once more, observe the flow of
>   breath and its effect.

Benefits of Chinmaya Mudra

> Improves flow of energy in the body
>
> Stimulates digestion

**Adi Mudra**

> In Adi Mudra, the thumb is placed at the base of the small finger and
>   the remaining fingers curl over the thumb, forming a light fist. The
>   palms are again placed facing upwards on the thighs and the breathing
>   repeated.

Benefits of Adi Mudra

> Relaxes the nervous system
>
> Helps reduce snoring
>
> Improves the flow of oxygen to the head
>
> Increases capacity of the lungs

It also says this:

> In each *yoga mudra*, take at least twelve breaths and closely observe
>   the flow of energy in the body.
>
> There are numerous different mudras, many mysterious and others
>   contemporary in nature. The main texts concerning the use of mudras
>   are the *Hatha Yoga Pradipika* and *Gheranda Samhita*. The Hatha Yoga
>   Pradipika describes *10* mudras and the Gheranda Samhita *25*.
>
> Some Yoga mudras come natural to us. Simply by touching our hands to
>   our fingers, we can affect our attitude and our perception and the
>   inherent energetic power can heal the body. There is a direct
>   relationship between the mudras and the five elements of the body.
>
> According to *Ayurveda*, diseases are caused due to an imbalance in
>   the body, which in turn is caused by lack or excess of any of the five
>   elements. Our fingers have the characteristics of these elements and
>   each of these five elements serve a specific and important function
>   within the body. The fingers are essentially electrical circuits. The
>   use of mudras adjusts the flow of energy - affecting the balance of
>   air, fire, water, earth, ether and accommodating healing.
>
> There are many interpretations of the various finger positions.
>   Whether they are represented as aspects of the self, the three
>   energies inherent in the gunas, the mind, intellect, ego, illusion or
>   karma, remains a mystery. The main point being that they introduce a
>   non-intellectual sensibility.
>
> Yoga mudras are practiced sitting simply cross-legged, in *Vajrasana*,
>   or in lotus posture, or even by sitting comfortably in a chair.
>   Ideally, *Ujjai* breathing accompanies the more simple mudras.

Comment: i like your answer, it will add as asset to the question, but i was looking types of mudras too.

Comment: @Mr.K: I have added some of the major ones, I could add more too but that will make the answer very long. Let me know :)

Comment: its ok phantom has already added some branches name, thanks for A2A

Answer (score 0):

Mudra are hand gestures which are used by yogi in meditation, they are different types of **[hand mudras](http://yogainstantly.com/yoga-mudra-and-their-benefits/)** on the basis of special features and abilities.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to [Hinduism.SE] , Please take a [tour] of our site and read [ask], [answer] pages. Also see [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/5212).